# How to change view after login process is complete

Tags: ios, swift

```
func login(id:String?, password:String? ) {

    var result:SimpleResult = SimpleResult(result: true, message: nil)


    let parameters: Parameters = ["username":id, "password":password]


    let request:NetworkRequest = NetworkRequest()

    request.sendPostRequest(url: NetworkInformation.serverAddr + "/login", parameters: parameters, success: loginHandler, fail: request.CommonNetworkFailureHandler)
}



func loginHandler(response:Any){
    let json = JSON(response)
    let responseResult = json["result"]
    var resultMessage:String = ResultMessage.MESSAGE_SUCCESS_CREATE_ACCOUNT


    if responseResult == true{
        print("login success")
          //change view

    }

    else{
        let am:AlertManager = AlertManager()
        am.showSimpleAlertMessage(title: "login failed", message: ResultMessage.MESSAGE_ERROR_LOGIN)

    }
}
```

Hi I'm new to swift 
Inside 'login' function, login process is done using Alamofire and the code flow moves to 'loginHandler' function.

If 'responseResult' is true, I want to change view. 
How can I do that?

Comment: What are you using? Storyboard or XIB's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Storyboard

```
if responseResult == true{
    print("login success")
      //change view
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController;
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

For XIB's

```
if responseResult == true{
    print("login success")
      //change view
    let vc = SecondViewController();
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use segue to go to another view controller.
- Or you can set the Root navigation controller of login controller and push the next view controller.
  or if you want to do in same view controller, Add another UIVIEW and set the frame of UIVIEW to hide or show.